# Not able to use dotenv because of Module not found

Tags: angular, variables, environment-variables, cicd, dotenv

i would like to get back a CICD variable value from my gitlab repo when pushing code into deployement. I just followed this [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and this [doc](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/blob/master/README.md). To do that I need to use **dotenv** as follow:

```
import env from './.env';

import 'dotenv/config'
console.log(process.env) 

//ENV DEV
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  version: env.npm_package_version + '-dev',
  serverUrl: '',
  defaultLanguage: 'en-US',
  supportedLanguages: ['en-US', 'fr-FR', 'es-ES'],

  //Base de données 'firestore' and 'realtime database' from FIREBASE => BD DEV gbl-ist-ve-dlaaas-dev
  firebaseApp: {
  apiKey: `${process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY}`,
  other....
  }
}
```

*FIREBASE_API_KEY* is in my app.yaml and in my deploy.sh, both executed when the CICD pipeline triggers the job deploy so no trouble here, the deployement is OK and the var is set correctly in my CICD variables. But I'm still not able to retrieve the value of FIREBASE_API_KEY throught *env.process* SO I just want to try it in local, process.env is well defined.

The trouble is that, I'm faced to the error when I'm building my app:
[image: Error prompted]

I tried to install webpack but same error nothing changed...
Thanks